# How to resolve Appstore business information metadata rejection

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, metadata

My app was rejected by the appstore review board, and they are requesting some additional information:

> - Who is the target audience?
> - Is the app to be used by users within one single company?
> - Identify the countries or regions where you plan to distribute your app.
> - What features in the app are intended for use by general App Store users?
> - How do users obtain an account?

But the problem is that I've searched everywhere on appstore connect, but couldn't find anywhere to fill in the requested information.

Has anyone had to deal with this, your input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

hope you are doing great!
I had a similar situation where the *Apple review team* asked me for some details about the app. Just provide them as detailed answers as possible and make sure to include some links to your app metadata like the website so that it is easy for them to review/verify your claims.

Comment: Am I supposed to provide them as a reply?

Comment: Yes, You need to just reply :)